# C# Linking windows form with already created classes and console

Tags: c#, winforms, console

The question: How can i link the user input to a specific constructor and create an object when the user clicks on Add.

How i created my project:

I created a console application. A class named car with the following attributes:

- Brand name
- Type
- Mileage
- Commissioning date
- Numberplate
- Horsepower
- Number of gears
- Number of seats
- Volume of the trunk
- Fuel consumption

**2 Constructors:** 1 with everything except number of seats. Second with everything except number of gears.

**A method** that adds to the fuel consumption depending on how many numbers of gears or number of seats.

Everything works well. I now created a windows form. Changed output type to windows form instead of console.

**For the windows form:**

The user has to choose between **2 options:** A sports car or a family car. Depending on which option the user chooses, for the sports car all attributes except for number of seats. For the family car, everything except for number of gears. The user has to fill in the name of the car, type, etc.

Then the user needs to click on the button named **Add** in order to see the consumption of the vehicle. Later in the project, i need to create it so that the user is able to delete it by typing in the numberplate.

```
namespace Sportwagens {
    public class Wagen
    {
        string Merk;
        string Type;
        int Aantalkm;
        DateTime Ingebruiknamedatum;
        string Nummerplaat;
        int Pk;
        int Brandstofverbruik;

    public class Sportwagen : Wagen
    {
        int Aantalvitessen;

        public Sportwagen(string merk, string type, int aantalkm, DateTime ingebruiknamedatum, string nummerplaat, int pk, int aantalvitessen, int brandstofverbruik)
        {
            Merk = merk;
            Type = type;
            Aantalkm = aantalkm;
            Ingebruiknamedatum = ingebruiknamedatum;
            Nummerplaat = nummerplaat;
            Pk = pk;
            Aantalvitessen = aantalvitessen;
            Brandstofverbruik = brandstofverbruik;
        }

        public int vermeerderingbrandsotfverbruiksportwagen()
        {
            if (Aantalvitessen >= 6)
            {
                Brandstofverbruik += 2;
            }
            return Brandstofverbruik;
        }
    }

    class Gezinswagen : Wagen
    {
        int Aantalzitplaatsen;
        int Koffervolume;

        public Gezinswagen(string merk, string type, int aantalkm, DateTime ingebruiknamedatum, string nummerplaat, int pk, int aantalzitplaatsen, int koffervolume, int brandstofverbruik)
        {
            Merk = merk;
            Type = type;
            Aantalkm = aantalkm;
            Ingebruiknamedatum = ingebruiknamedatum;
            Nummerplaat = nummerplaat;
            Pk = pk;
            Aantalzitplaatsen = aantalzitplaatsen;
            Koffervolume = koffervolume;
            Brandstofverbruik = brandstofverbruik;

        }

        public int vermeerderingbrandsotfverbruikgezinswagen()
        {

            if (Aantalzitplaatsen >= 7)
            {
                Brandstofverbruik += 1;
            }
            return Brandstofverbruik;
        }
    }

public Wagen()
    {

    }
    public Wagen(string merk, string type, int aantalkm, DateTime ingebruiknamedatum, string nummerplaat)
    {
        Merk = merk;
        Type = type;
        Aantalkm = aantalkm;
        Ingebruiknamedatum = ingebruiknamedatum;
        Nummerplaat = nummerplaat;
    }
```

[Click here to see how the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovJQB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'car' object is instantiated when the user chooses between the two options, you could simply change the order of the arguments in each constructor (assuming that there are arguments of different types).

For example, if one constructor was:

```
public Car(string brandName, string type, double mileage ...)
{
    ...
}
```

And the other was:

```
public Car(string brandName, double mileage, string type ...)
{
    ...
}
```

You could force the class to use one or the other based on the order in which you give the parameters. However this is not good practice.

**From your description, it sounds as though you should create two 'subclasses', (SportsCar and FamilyCar) and use inheritance to achieve your goal, or composition.**

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a great deal! One more question, so i have 2 subclasses, Sportscar and Familycar. If the user chooses for example Sportscar and fills in everything else, clicks on Add, how do i declare and initialize an object with the user input?

Comment: Assuming that Sportscar inherits from Car: Declare a Sportscar outside the button click function:
    Sportscar mySportsCar;
Then the function should look something like this:
    private void button1_click(...)
    {
        mySportsCar = new Sportscar(brandName etc..);
    }

putting in the parameters as required.
It may help if you copy and paste your code into the question up there ^^^ so I can see what you are talking about

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you correctly. So if the user clicks on the button, with the information the user inserted in the form, i want to create an object. I know how to create an object but i don't know how to create an object with information that is given via the form. mySportsCar = new Sportscar(the information the user inserted but how?) I've put my code in the question and a link to the image on how the form looks like. The identifiers are in Dutch, i could perhaps change it to English if it helps you solve my question. Thank you again Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the "Toevoegen" button in the form editor. That should create a method that looks a bit like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Outside the method, declare an instance of the 'Wagen' class like so:

```
Wagen mijnWagen;
```

Then, inside the button_click method, initialise the instance of the wagen object as follows:

```
if (//"Sportswagen is selected")
{
    mijnWagen = new Sportwagen(merk, type etc. as filled in on form);
}
else
{
    mijnWagen = new Gezinswagen(merk, type etc. as filled in on form);
}
```

Now, when the button is clicked, the object mijnWagen will be initialised to whichever type of car they selected.